# Spatial bound on the internal electron structure

Tags: quantum-field-theory, point-particles

In 2006 the radius for a possible internal structure of the electron has been pinned down to $10^{-18} m$. This validates the approximation of electrons as point particles at long distances, e.g. in an atom. The upper bound on the internal electron radius has been derived from a very precise measurement of the $g$-factor, see

[New Measurement of the Electron Magnetic Moment Using a One-Electron Quantum Cyclotron](http://gabrielse.physics.harvard.edu/gabrielse/papers/2006/HarvardElectronMagneticMoment2006.pdf)

What I don't understand is how did they determine the relation between the $g$-facor and the radius of the internal structure?

As far as I understand they compare the $g$ factor of a point particle to the $g$ factor of an extend particle. But how do you calculate the $g$ factor of a point particle or an extend particle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how do you calculate the g factor of a point particle or an extend particle?

This is done for a point particle, and any experimental deviation from the calculated value for a point particle would suggest structure beyond a point particle.

Dirac theory predicts g=2.

Anomaly from g=2 has QED, hadronic and weak contributions, which are each calculated.  The hadronic and weak contributions are small and considered to be well understood.

The QED contribution to the anomaly is the main contribution and extremely difficult to calculate.  Hundreds of Feymann diagrams are involved.

See [New Determination of the Fine Structure Constant from the Electron g Value and QED](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.97.030802) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can you also explain in short, where in Dirac theory $g = 2$ occurs, so what do I have to do if I start at Dirac's equation? I'd like to see it by myself in order to better understand it. (I already had a basic course on QED, but I only remember that it was mentioned somewhere in a small comment.)

Comment: there is a derivation here: http://www.phy.ohiou.edu/~elster/lectures/relqm_10.pdf